# JPanels content doesn't reshow

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, show

I had spent two days in solving this problem but I have not found any solution.
I will put some easy code.

There is JFrame with some menu Bar, JPanels, but we focus on 2 options:

"Create Server"

"Close connection"

When I create server, on JPanel I draw checkerboard, and when I close connection, JPanel is clean, but the problem begins when I want to create server one more time, **JPanel shows nothing.**

1. I checked the input JPanel, and I put required JPanel before recreate server - nothing
2. I thought maybe it's gameControl, but I use it in other cases and it works also.

If anybody wants to try:

Here is entire project: http://bycniebytem.cba.pl/checkers.rar

Problem is inside the Checkers.java class,

But I'm waiting for your advices! **Thanks!**

```
 hostServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            hostServer.setEnabled(false);
            closeConnection.setEnabled(true);

            server = new Server();
            try 
            {
                JPanel networkPanel = new JPanel();
                player1 = new Player(1,boardSize, fieldSize);

                player1.gameControl.setBounds(10, 10, boardSize*fieldSize + 10, boardSize*fieldSize + 10);
                player1.gameControl.setSize(boardSize*fieldSize, boardSize*fieldSize);
                player1.gameControl.addMouseListener(player1.gameControl);
                player1.gameControl.addMouseMotionListener(player1.gameControl);
                player1.gameControl.setFocusable(true);

                player1.gameControl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(boardSize*fieldSize,boardSize*fieldSize));
                player1.connectWithServer(server.serverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

                JPanel votePanel = new JPanel();
                JRadioButton whiteRadioButton = new JRadioButton("White");
                JRadioButton blackRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Black");
                blackRadioButton.setBounds(1, 1, 100, 30);
                whiteRadioButton.setBounds(1, blackRadioButton.getHeight() + 5, 100, 30);

                JButton bReady = new JButton("Ready");
                bReady.setBounds(1, whiteRadioButton.getHeight() + 5, 100, 30);
                ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
                radioGroup.add(whiteRadioButton);
                radioGroup.add(blackRadioButton);

                votePanel.add(blackRadioButton);
                votePanel.add(whiteRadioButton);
                votePanel.add(bReady);

                votePanel.setBounds(player1.gameControl.getWidth() + 10, 10, blackRadioButton.getWidth(), blackRadioButton.getHeight() * 3);
                votePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(blackRadioButton.getWidth(), player1.gameControl.getHeight()));

                setSize(boardSize * fieldSize + votePanel.getWidth() + 50, getJMenuBar().getHeight() + boardSize * fieldSize + 20); 

                networkPanel.add(player1.gameControl);
                networkPanel.add(votePanel);

                add(networkPanel);
                setContentPane(networkPanel);
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
            }                
        }
    });
```

**And close connection**

```
   closeConnection.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try 
            {
                if(server != null)
                {
                    if(server.getPlayerBlackSocket() != null)
                    {   
                        server.sendMessage(server.getPlayerBlackSocket(), "closeConnection");
                        server.getPlayerBlackSocket().close();
                    }
                    if(server.getPlayerWhiteSocket() != null)
                    {
                        server.sendMessage(server.getPlayerWhiteSocket(), "closeConnection");
                        server.getPlayerWhiteSocket().close();
                    }                        
                    if(server.getServerSocket() != null)
                    {
                        server.getServerSocket().close();
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
            }

            player1.isOpenedConnection = false;

            JPanel pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
            pane.removeAll();
            remove(pane);

            JPanel Pan = new JPanel();
            JLabel label = new JLabel("label"); // just to test if jpanel can show and it shows
            label.setBounds(10,10,100,30);
            Pan.add(label);
            setContentPane(Pan);
            revalidate();
            repaint();

            closeConnection.setEnabled(false);
            hostServer.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: regarding this code: `catch(IOException ex) { }` Never ignore exceptions as you're doing. Your code could be blowing up on you, and you'd never know it, and that my friend makes for very dangerous code. Just don't do it. At least print the exception's stacktrace.

Comment: I removed it only for demands stackoverflow (its to much code)

Comment: Don't use setSize(). Use a layout manager. And when you re-create the panel, set it's preferred size, then revalidate its parent.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaa! I CAN"T BELIEVE IT! It works! How can I give you a big point here?